# 503 response on Facebook Linter

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, httpresponse

i'm getting response 503 from Facebook linter while my website is accessible, what went wrong?
[Facebook linter result - 504](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.melaka3.com)
[My website. Melaka3.com - Melaka reviews](http://www.melaka3.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it was Blogger problem and they are fixing it now.
[Google Forum Thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/bloggerdev/9rVo0mny7Do/discussion)

Mine seems to be fixed now but someone else on the thread is still experiencing the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this happens to you, maybe server settings or something like that, but from the checks I did it does look like there's something wrong on your side.

When you go to the linter result page for your url, at the bottom click the link "Scraped URL:   See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL" to see what facebook received from your server. It says:

> Document returned no data

I also tried to curl your url, which worked just fine, I then tried:

```
curl --user-agent "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)" "http://www.melaka3.com"
```

And the response I get keeps changing, it's either the right html code (the same I see when I view the source in the browser) but in a lot of cases I get:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Service Unavailable</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Service Unavailable</H1>
<H2>Error 503</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Which explains what facebook outputs in the linter.

Comment: a friend of mine found this. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/151988841572175?browse=search_4f5f5e86b466b5d58920553

Comment: This does not seem to help you in any way, since I got the 503 from your server when I issued a request from my machine using curl. I just added the user agent so that your server will think the request came from facebook. This seems like a problem with your server (hosting service) and not a problem with facebook, and so I don't see how a bug report on facebook will help you